# Реализация паттерна команды

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучаю java по видеоурокам, на курсах дали задачу реализовать паттерн "комманды".

> В качестве аргументов метод main будет получать команды. Например, для
>   команды echo Hello World, метод main получит массив с ДВУХ элементов {
>   "echo", "Hello World"}. Для команды date now также будет ДВА аргументы
>   { "date", "now"}.
>
> При реализации воспользуйтесь поддержкой полиморфизма времени
>   выполнения. Фактически Вам нужно создавать экземпляр реализации
>   конкретной команды в зависимости от набора входных данных. Типом
>   ссылки на конкретный экземпляр будет Command, таким образом вызов
>   конкретной команды будет сведено к command.execute() 
>   В случае если команда не известна, или содержит не верное количество аргументов
>   выведите на экран надпись Error

Реализовал сам паттерн,не могу понять как сделать чтобы вызов был как в задании.

Разобрался с проблемой,возникла новая,при проверке скрипт выдает мне ошибку

> Running com.tasks5.command.CommandTest
>
> Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.468 sec
>
> <<< FAILURE! - in com.tasks5.command.CommandTest
>
> testNullArgs(com.tasks5.command.CommandTest)  Time elapsed: 0.044 sec
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>     at com.tasks5.command.Cmd.execute(Application.java:31)
>     at com.tasks5.command.Application.main(Application.java:11)
>     at com.tasks5.command.CommandTest.testNullArgs(CommandTest.java:86)

java:

```
package com.tasks5.command;

public class Application {
    static String a;
    static String b;
    static String[] c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cmd command = new Cmd();
        c = args;
        if (args == null) {
            c = null;
        }
        command.execute();
        //YOUR CODE COMES HERE
    }
}

interface Command {
    void execute();
}

class App {
    void help() {
        System.out.println("Help executed");
    }

    void echo() {
        Application t = new Application();
        System.out.println(t.c[1]);
    }

    void date() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    void exit() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}

class Cmd implements Command {
    public void execute() {
        App a = new App();
        User u = new User(new help(a), new echo(a), new date(a), new exit(a));
        Application a1 = new Application();
        if (a1.c.length == 0 || a1.c.length > 2 || a1.c == null) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        } else if (a1.c[0].equals("help") && a1.c.length == 1) {
            u.help();
        } else if (a1.c[0].equals("echo") && a1.c[1] != null && a1.c[1] != "null" && a1.c.length == 2) {
            u.echo();
        } else if (a1.c[0].equals("date") && a1.c[1].equals("now") && a1.c.length == 2) {
            u.date();
        } else if (a1.c[0].equals("exit") && a1.c.length == 1) {
            u.exit();
        } else System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

//command "help"
class help implements Command {
    App command = new App();

    public help(App command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
        command.help();
    }
}

//command "echo text"
class echo implements Command {
    App command = new App();

    public echo(App command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
        command.echo();
    }
}

//command "date now"
class date implements Command {
    App command = new App();

    public date(App command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
        command.date();
    }
}

//command "exit"
class exit implements Command {
    App command = new App();

    public exit(App command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
        command.exit();
    }
}

//Vizov commandi;
class User {
    Command help;
    Command echo;
    Command date;
    Command exit;

    public User(Command help, Command echo, Command date, Command exit) {
        this.help = help;
        this.echo = echo;
        this.date = date;
        this.exit = exit;
    }

    void help() {
        help.execute();
    }

    void echo() {
        echo.execute();
    }

    void date() {
        date.execute();
    }

    void exit() {
        exit.execute();
    }
}
```

Разобрался сам. Всем кто помогал спасибо.

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Comment: @dmtr Отформатировал.

Comment: класcу `User` добавить `implements Command`

Comment: Я не понимаю как передавать значение аргументов команде? То есть, аргументы при проверке задания будет определять проверяюший скрипт,мне надо сделать так чтобы моя команда выполнялась при заданных аргументах: help,echo<text>,date now,exit. При других же должна быть ошибка

Comment: Добавьте аргументы в конструктор команды